# Netbeans accuse nonexistent errors (i guess)

Tags: java, jsp, web

I'm new to Java world and I'm having problems with ArrayList:

Here is my code:

```
package ontologia;

import br.ufal.ic.joint.RepositoryFacade;
import br.ufal.ic.joint.module.ontology.operations.OntologyCompiler;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author Mauricio
 */
public class NewClass {

    // Caminho do arquivo jar que será gerado
    String ontologyPath = "C:/family.jar";
    // URL da ontologia que deseja ser compilada
    String ontologyURL = "file:///C:/bbcOntology.owl";
    List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

    lista.add(ontologyURL);
    // Chama a fachada do JOINT
    RepositoryFacade fachada = new RepositoryFacade();
    OntologyCompiler compiler = fachada.getOntologyCompiler(ontologyPath, lista); // Gerador do JOINT
    compiler.compile(); // Compila a ontologia em classes Java
}
```

I'm programming on Netbeans and it is accusing errors on `lista.add(ontologyURL);`

Am I doing something wrong?

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: I think you are missing imports. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: "package lista does not exist"

Comment: Do you have List and ArrayList import on top of your class?

Comment: import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

Have both.

Comment: I've uploaded a screenshot.

Comment: Can we see some more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code (logical statements) should be inside some method, not directly inside class.

```
public class NewClass {
  public void someMethod()
   {
    //Here your code goes.
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks!

I forgot about that!

Comment: @Nambari can you solve this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421506/android-xml-parsing-returning-the-node-name